# How to get border line on textField from cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, uitextfield

I have a UITableView and inside UITableViewCell there are 5 textFields.
I have to assign UITextFieldDelegate and want to create border line on textField. I am calling my function createBorderLine from cellForRowAtIndexPath but it's throwing an error (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value).

Below is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let identifier = "EditProductCell"

        var editProductCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? EditProductCell
        if(editProductCell == nil)
        {
            let nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("EditProductCell", owner: self, options: nil)!
            editProductCell = nib[0] as? EditProductCell

            //Call Create Border Line function.
            self.createBorderLine()
        }
}
```

And here is my createBorderLine function:

```
func createBorderLine()
{
    let index : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let tCell : EditProductCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: index as IndexPath) as! EditProductCell

    tCell.InvoiceDate.delegate = self
    tCell.InvoiceNumber.delegate = self
    tCell.modelNumber.delegate = self
    tCell.productName.delegate = self
    tCell.serialNumber.delegate = self
    tCell.viewWarrentyDate.isHidden = true


    setBottomBorder(textField: tCell.InvoiceDate, width: 0.8,color : UIColor.lightGray)
    setBottomBorder(textField: tCell.InvoiceNumber, width: 0.8,color : UIColor.lightGray)
    setBottomBorder(textField: tCell.modelNumber, width: 0.8,color : UIColor.lightGray)
    setBottomBorder(textField: tCell.productName, width: 0.4,color : UIColor.lightGray)
    setBottomBorder(textField: tCell.serialNumber, width: 0.4,color : UIColor.lightGray)
}
```

What can I do? Why it is giving an error?

Comment: Why are you creating `let index : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)` ? You can just pass the cell object to createBorderLine

Comment: OK 
Actually I am Little bit confused in TableViewConcepts.
Basics I know.
Anyways Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you creating indexpath for row 0 and section 0 every time in createBorderLine. Simply pass the cell ref in  createBorderLine

```
self.createBorderLine(editProductCell)
```

and in `createBorderLine` function

```
 func createBorderLine(tCell: EditProductCell)
 {

tCell.InvoiceDate.delegate = self
tCell.InvoiceNumber.delegate = self
tCell.modelNumber.delegate = self
tCell.productName.delegate = self
tCell.serialNumber.delegate = self
tCell.viewWarrentyDate.isHidden = true


setBottomBorder(textField: tCell.InvoiceDate, width: 0.8,color : UIColor.lightGray)
setBottomBorder(textField: tCell.InvoiceNumber, width: 0.8,color : UIColor.lightGray)
setBottomBorder(textField: tCell.modelNumber, width: 0.8,color : UIColor.lightGray)
setBottomBorder(textField: tCell.productName, width: 0.4,color : UIColor.lightGray)
setBottomBorder(textField: tCell.serialNumber, width: 0.4,color : UIColor.lightGray)

}
```

Instead  of creating `createBorderLine` in Controller Class you should put `createBorderLine` in `EditProductCell` class. and call directly through EditProductCell object ref.

Comment: Yes I tried This and Its working.
Is there any other way also ?

Comment: i suggest you to put createBorderLine in EditProductCell class. so you can directly access createBorderLine through EditProductCell ref in cellForRowAt indexPath method.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking the same.
But I have change border line colour when tap on a textField and also for click a button.
thanks

Comment: You can simply implement the textfield delegate methods in controller class by writing editProductCell.yourTextField.delegate = self in cellForRowAt IndexPath.

Comment: Yeah Ok.
I will try that one also .
Anyways Thanks @Sahil